# ng-class with scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<div ng-repeat="app in fields track by $index">
   <span class="{{app.icon}}"></span>
   <span ng-class="app.icon"></span>
</div>

var originalFields = [
  {title: 'Text Field', icon: 'fa-pencil'},
  {title: 'Multiple Choice'}
];
```

These classes are working correctly the first time

When i used something like this `$scope.fields = angular.copy(originalFields);`

Then it works sometimes, but doesn't work sometimes I get `class="app.icon"` instead of `class="fa-edit"`

I even tried using `$scope.$apply();` after copying, but it doesn't work

value in `app.icon = "fa-edit"`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example code that shows this problem?

Comment: Can you give me the working fiddler link?

Comment: solved it while making a plnkr.co demo, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="app in fields">
   <span class="{{app.icon}}"></span>
   <span ng-class="app.icon"></span>
</div>
```

I have removed the `track by $index` It is working fine.

When First element got deleted it is copying second element's properties when using `track by $index`, My first element icon property is being overridden by second element. Second element doesn't have `icon` property.

Strange!!